# remove method implementation for binary search tree in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

[Here](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/ds/search-trees.html#remove) is one implementation of the `remove` method for `BST`. I quote from there:

```
 Removing an element from a search tree, although tricky, 
 is conceptually straight-forward with one (common) exception: removing the element at a 
  node with two non-null children. In this case, the solution is either:

 removeMax: remove the maximum (rightmost) node from the left subtree 
 and replace the root's value with the value of the removed node.
 removeMin: remove the minimum (leftmost) node from the right subtree 
 and replace the root's value with the value of the removed node.

    In either case the search tree's order structure is preserved.
```

If you look at this binary tree,[image]

I want to remove `8` and if I choose to pick element from `leftTree`, using `removeMax`, I will choose `7` according to the above definition.

but I need to choose `13` from `right Tree` using `removeMin` and that breaks the `BST`.

am I not understanding this correctly?

The way `remove` works is getting the either the `maximum` from the leftTree or `minimum` from the `rightTree` and replace the `node` to be removed with its `data`.

Comment: Why do you think it breaks the BST? It doesn't.

Comment: @EJP: According to the `removeMin` definition above, I need to remove the `leftmost` node of right subtree, which I see it as `13` but apparently it is not from answers below, I dont know why yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the visual appearance, the leftmost node of the right subtree above is ten, not 13. Reaching 13 requires moving right (from ten to 14), so 13 cannot be the leftmost node. If you choose ten, the BST property would not be broken.

The right subtree has three nodes - 10, 14, and 13.

```
   10
     \
      \
       14
      /
     13
```

Ten (at the top) has no left subtree, so it is the leftmost node of the right subtree.

> what if 10's leftnode is not `null` but some node?

Then the tree would look like this:

```
   10
  /  \
 /    \
9      14
      /
     13
```

so the leftmost node would be nine, not ten. Then the algorithm that you describe would pick nine for removal, which would again preserve the BST property.

Comment: why `13` cannot be left node...I am getting confused?

Comment: @user1988876 Because `10 < 13.`

Comment: The left subtree of `10` is just `null` and it has only `right subtree`

Comment: @user1988876 Correct. That's why it's leftmost - to get to the leftmost node, you start at the top, and go left while you can. Once you cannot go left any longer, you have reached the leftmost node. For the subtree in question, the state when you can no longer go left is reached immediately, hence ten is the leftmost node. Note that the leftmost node does not have to be a leaf node - it may have descendents on the right.

Comment: what if `10`'s leftnode is not `null` but some `node`

Comment: @user1988876 Edited - please take a look.

Comment: that is clear. but regards to `remove` method, I will go down the tree to find the `minimum` or the `leftmost` node of the right subtree, copy its `data` and return the right node of the copied element..and replace the root` with the copied data

Comment: @user1988876 Correct. You will go down the right subtree for its leftmost node (ten), remove that node, and replace the root (eight) with its data. Now the root is ten, with children of 3 on the left and 14 on the right.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value from the right subtree is 10, not 13.

Something that might help if you need a visual mnemonic: the minimum value of a right subtree is the "leftmost descendent of the right child."

Comment: Okay it's like this.  You want the minimum value in the entire right subtree of the 8.  So start at the top of this subtree.  This is the node with the 10 in it.  Okay so all numbers smaller than 10 will be to the left of 10.  But there aren't any, so 10 is the minimum!  Now if there **were** left children of the 10, perhaps 9 and 8.5 then you would find them by descdending as far down to the left as you can go.  So we say the leftmost descendent of the right child.  It could be the right child itself, which in your case, it is.